# mysql insert find next in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, this one is hard to explain in the title.

I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `ordering` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The `ordering` column is normally set in the client-- that is, the client can drag and reorder these categories, so it is not auto_incremented.

My question is, when I want to insert a row outside the client using a direct SQL insert is there a way to quickly get the max of the `ordering` column in the same statement?

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (title, desc, ordering)
VALUES ('test title', 'description', (SELECT max(ordering) FROM `categories`)+1);
```

I've tried a dozen variations on this theme with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to get that to work is to avoid using the VALUES clause, and instead use a SELECT as the rowsource for the INSERT,

something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (title, desc, ordering)
SELECT 'test title', 'description', MAX(ordering)+1 FROM `categories`
```

NOTE: This may work with MyISAM tables, which disallows concurrent inserts. But for other engines that allow concurrent INSERTS, this approach will likely be "broken by design". I don't think there is any guarantee that two INSERT statements running concurrently won't generate the same value for the ordering column.

This design is also "broken by design" when the categories table is empty, because MAX(ordering) would return a NULL. But an IFNULL function can fix that.

```
SELECT 'test title', 'description', IFNULL(MAX(ordering),0)+1 FROM `categories`
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
insert into `categories` (`title`, `desc`, `ordering`) 
select 'test title','description', max(ordering) + 1 FROM `categories`
```